# Number Helper - how to return the currency symbol only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency

I am usually using the function `number_to_currency` of `ActionView::Base` in order to get a number formatted in a specific currency. But I need to get the currency symbol only (to display it next to a textfield.

I did not find a better way than `I18n.t(:'number.currency.format.unit')`. Any better recommendation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format using the currency symbol but no value, i.e. with a format of just `%u`:

```
number_to_currency 1, format: '%u'
   #=> "$"
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you want is the currency symbol, can you just grab the first element of the string?

```
number_to_currency(39.50)[0] = "$"
```

Or if you want everything except the currency symbol

```
number_to_currency(39.50)[1..-1] = "39.50"
```

Comment: It does not work for all currencies : for example euro comes after the number.

Comment: I see. I think the best way would then be what you currently have. It's what number_to_currency uses as its source anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I keep this solution and post later if I  can find something better.